# UIPopoverController not showing properly in iOS 8/9

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a piece of code pointing a UIPopoverController to a menu item in iOS 8/9, it was working in iOS7 and in fact it's in production on the App Store. For some reason, it doesn't show properly when I tried to test the code on iOS 8/9.

[image]

For some reason, the iOS framework inserts the black shadow thing about 75% of the screen. It's like it thinks the device is in portrait mode. My app is always in the landscape mode. Portrait is not considered.

When I click on the area outside the dark shadow, I get:

```
_UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent, _windowServerHitTestWindow: <UIWindow: 0x1355065a0; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x174645520>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x174223920>>
```

I suspect something is making the framework believes the app is running portrait. The error message above is saying the area outside the dark shadow has no respondent to my clicking action. It's my suspicion, I'm not 100% sure.

and the code:

```
-(void) showActionControllerByPopover:(UIViewController *)actionController item:(UIBarButtonItem *)item
{
    UINavigationController * const navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:actionController];
    [navController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];

    [_popController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    _popController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];

    [_popController setDelegate:self];

        [_popController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 768)];        

    [_popController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:item
                           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                           animated:YES];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you limited your target to run in landscape modes in your project file? (Project/Workspace | Target | General | Deployment Info | Device Orientation)

Comment: @DarrenBlack See edited...

Comment: I'd be surprised if the framework thinks you're in portrait mode then. Where is the code that displays the shadow?

Comment: @DarrenBlack As shown in the question. I didn't create the shadow myself, UIPopoverController automatically does it. It's supposed to cover the entire screen, but it's not in my case.